# React Testing Library element does not receive focus as expected

Tags: react-testing-library

I am trying to test a skip-nav I made in my Next.js app. When, clicked, the focus should switch to the main element. It works, however I cannot figure out how to test it using React Testing Library. I added focus color  and tabIndex to main so that I can see it working.

```js
// layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const mainId = 'main-content';
  return (
    <html lang="en" data-theme={'emerald'}>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <SkipNav mainId={mainId} />
        <Header />
        <main
          id={mainId}
          tabIndex={0}
          className="flex flex-col grow items-center focus:bg-primary"
        >
          {children}
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```js
// skip-nav.tsx
export default function SkipNav({ mainId }: SkipNavProps) {
  return (
    <a
      id="skip-nav"
      href={`#${mainId}`}
      className="bg-base-100 text-base-content p-3 text-sm absolute left-4 top-0 transform -translate-y-full 
        focus:z-10 focus:transition-transform focus:translate-y-0"
    >
      Skip to main content
    </a>
  );
}
```

```js
// skip-nav.spec.tsx
// This is not working. document.activeElement is anchor, even after clicking.
  it('should move focus to main element when clicked', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    const mainId = 'test-main-id';

    render(
      <div>
        <SkipNav mainId={mainId} />
        <main tabIndex={0} id={mainId} />
      </div>
    );
    const anchor = screen.getByRole('link', {
      name: 'Skip to main content'
    });
    const main = screen.getByRole('main');

    await user.click(anchor);
    await waitFor(() => expect(document.activeElement).toEqual(main));
  });
```